# Perl: determine the sql server data type of each column of a perl hash

Tags: sql-server, regex, perl

I am looking to take a large array of hashes that I pulled from DBI and return the data type of each column IE (datetime, varchar(#), int, etc.).  I built a perl module to do this using regex but as I would like it to be more verbose (ie nvarchar(#), float, etc.) I was wondering if there was a module that already exists to do this before I build it out.

Comment: Mainly depends on the SQL server being used. Should be in information_schema for mySQL.

Comment: You are using Microsoft SQL Server? Which driver do you use to connect with DBI?

Comment: Sorry I should clarify I have an arbitrary hash not from sql server that I iterate through and determine the best datatype for each column.  I've written 5 data types out using regex but before I continue I wanted to see if anyone knew of a module that exists with this functionality.

Comment: FreeTDS TDS Version 8.0

Answer (score 0):

I see you are looking for a module.  But doesn't the following DBI code help in some way:

```
$sth = $dbh->column_info( $catalog, $schema, $table, $column );
```

...

```
$sth->fetchall_arrayref or $sth->fetchall_hashref
```

...
etc

The `column_info` call should provide, via the statement handle, the following field:

```
DATA_TYPE: The concise data type code.
```

And that code could be used to determine the column data type.